# find square root of $x^2+x^3 $ in formal power series $k[[x,y]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations, formal-power-series

I am trying to show that the polynomial $y-x^2-x^3$ is reducible in the formal power series ring $k[[x,y]]$. I am attempting the question by finding a polynomial in $k[[x,y]]$ which is the square root of $x^2+x^3$. In order to find the square root I wrote the general polynomial in $k[[x,y]]$, $$a_{00}+a_{10}x+a_{01}y+a_{20}x^2 ...........$$ Took it's square and equated the coefficients to the coefficients of $x^2+x^3$. I got the following system of equations

$$a_{00}^2=0$$
$$2a_{10} a_{00}=0$$
$$2a_{20} a_{00}+{a_{10}}^2=1 $$
and so on. But this system doesnot have a solution. I am sure that the root does exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By the generalized binomial theorem  we have
$$
\sqrt{x^2+x^3}=|x| (1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=|x| \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{i}x^i,
$$
where
$$
\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{i}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-1)(\frac{1}{2}-2) \cdots (\frac{1}{2}-i+1)}{i!}
$$